# Bootstrap 2.3.2 overlapping divs in grid on browser window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have two divs that are overlapping using Bootstrap's 2.3.2 grid system when the browser is resized. The result looks like the following after you downsize the browser window:

[image]

I don't want the two divs to ever overlap. If it comes to a point where they cannot fit on the same row, the second div should fall below the first, which the responsive layout is already doing. My problem is those weird few pixels where they overlap.

I'm using Bootstrap's tags input library here.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div class="span1 offset4" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        <select id="container" multiple data-role="tagsinput"> </select>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 offset2" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <h4>
              Second Div
              </h4>
        <div id="second_div">
          <p>
            testing...... 1 ... 2 ... 3...
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript to populate some dummy data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'Foo');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'Bar');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'This is a very very very very very very long filter');
});
```

And my CSS:

```
.small {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.tag {
  /*height: 25px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25px;
  /*width: 75%;*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-margin {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: none;
}
```

I have a jsfiddle which demos the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/brseyg6c/

Comment: I hope if you add this line and check maybe its work for you @media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px){
.row-fluid .span2  {
    margin-left: 24.889503%;
 }
}
If not, try with !important. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/kcohs9ov/ ]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Bootstrap but instead this declaration:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: none;
}
```

You're fixing the width of the tag container while it's inside a dynamically sized Bootstrap column.

Instead, have the container fill the width of the column:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You might want to increase the width of the left column (change `span1` to be larger) and remove the offset from the right column.

Comment: I want to have a fixed width for `.bootstrap-tagsinput`, that's why I have that declaration there. Going with `width: 100%` has the tags bleed outside of the container.

Comment: Can you not then set `max-width: 100%` on the tags?

Answer (score 0):

I have two idea for you. 
 Trick 1: Can you make it like this with out media query just replace the **off-set2** and make offset3. and add this  into class .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag white-space:pre-wrap; .otherwise in snippet large tag came out of the box. [Trick 2 Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/53j2qmxa/1/)

```
  .bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #777;
  opacity: 1;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  margin-top: 5px;
  /* custom */
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
  margin-left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
  content: "x";
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

pre {
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

p {
  color: #000;
}

p a {
  color: #990033;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .25s;
  padding: 3px;
}

p a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #990033;
  transition: all .25s;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.small {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.tag {
  /*height: 25px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25px;
  /*width: 75%;*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-margin {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
    <head>
         <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script> 
     <script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script> 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>   
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div class="span1 offset4" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        <select id="container" multiple data-role="tagsinput"> </select>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 offset3" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <h4>
              Second Div 
              </h4>
        <div id="event-log">
          <p>
            testing...... 1 ... 2 ... 3...
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var defaultOptions = {
    tagClass: function(item) {
      return 'label label-info';
    },
    itemValue: function(item) {
      return item ? item.toString() : item;
    },
    itemText: function(item) {
      return this.itemValue(item);
    },
    itemTitle: function(item) {
      return null;
    },
    freeInput: true,
    addOnBlur: true,
    maxTags: undefined,
    maxChars: undefined,
    confirmKeys: [13, 44],
    delimiter: ',',
    delimiterRegex: null,
    cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty: true,
    onTagExists: function(item, $tag) {
      $tag.hide().fadeIn();
    },
    trimValue: false,
    allowDuplicates: false
  };

  /**
   * Constructor function
   */
  function TagsInput(element, options) {
    this.itemsArray = [];

    this.$element = $(element);
    this.$element.hide();

    this.isSelect = (element.tagName === 'SELECT');
    this.multiple = (this.isSelect && element.hasAttribute('multiple'));
    this.objectItems = options && options.itemValue;
    this.placeholderText = element.hasAttribute('placeholder') ? this.$element.attr('placeholder') : '';
    this.inputSize = Math.max(1, this.placeholderText.length);

    this.$container = $('<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"></div>');
    this.$input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="' + this.placeholderText + '"/>').appendTo(this.$container);

    this.$element.before(this.$container);

    this.build(options);
  }

  TagsInput.prototype = {
    constructor: TagsInput,

    /**
     * Adds the given item as a new tag. Pass true to dontPushVal to prevent
     * updating the elements val()
     */
    add: function(item, dontPushVal, options) {
      var self = this;

      if (self.options.maxTags && self.itemsArray.length >= self.options.maxTags)
        return;

      // Ignore falsey values, except false
      if (item !== false && !item)
        return;

      // Trim value
      if (typeof item === "string" && self.options.trimValue) {
        item = $.trim(item);
      }

      // Throw an error when trying to add an object while the itemValue option was not set
      if (typeof item === "object" && !self.objectItems)
        throw ("Can't add objects when itemValue option is not set");

      // Ignore strings only containg whitespace
      if (item.toString().match(/^\s*$/))
        return;

      // If SELECT but not multiple, remove current tag
      if (self.isSelect && !self.multiple && self.itemsArray.length > 0)
        self.remove(self.itemsArray[0]);

      if (typeof item === "string" && this.$element[0].tagName === 'INPUT') {
        var delimiter = (self.options.delimiterRegex) ? self.options.delimiterRegex : self.options.delimiter;
        var items = item.split(delimiter);
        if (items.length > 1) {
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            this.add(items[i], true);
          }

          if (!dontPushVal)
            self.pushVal();
          return;
        }
      }

      var itemValue = self.options.itemValue(item),
        itemText = self.options.itemText(item),
        tagClass = self.options.tagClass(item),
        itemTitle = self.options.itemTitle(item);

      // Ignore items allready added
      var existing = $.grep(self.itemsArray, function(item) {
        return self.options.itemValue(item) === itemValue;
      })[0];
      if (existing && !self.options.allowDuplicates) {
        // Invoke onTagExists
        if (self.options.onTagExists) {
          var $existingTag = $(".tag", self.$container).filter(function() {
            return $(this).data("item") === existing;
          });
          self.options.onTagExists(item, $existingTag);
        }
        return;
      }

      // if length greater than limit
      if (self.items().toString().length + item.length + 1 > self.options.maxInputLength)
        return;

      // raise beforeItemAdd arg
      var beforeItemAddEvent = $.Event('beforeItemAdd', {
        item: item,
        cancel: false,
        options: options
      });
      self.$element.trigger(beforeItemAddEvent);
      if (beforeItemAddEvent.cancel)
        return;

      // register item in internal array and map
      self.itemsArray.push(item);

      // add a tag element

      var $tag = $('<span class="tag ' + htmlEncode(tagClass) + (itemTitle !== null ? ('" title="' + itemTitle) : '') + '">' + htmlEncode(itemText) + '<span data-role="remove"></span></span>');
      $tag.data('item', item);
      self.findInputWrapper().before($tag);
      $tag.after(' ');

      // add <option /> if item represents a value not present in one of the <select />'s options
      if (self.isSelect && !$('option[value="' + encodeURIComponent(itemValue) + '"]', self.$element)[0]) {
        var $option = $('<option selected>' + htmlEncode(itemText) + '</option>');
        $option.data('item', item);
        $option.attr('value', itemValue);
        self.$element.append($option);
      }

      if (!dontPushVal)
        self.pushVal();

      // Add class when reached maxTags
      if (self.options.maxTags === self.itemsArray.length || self.items().toString().length === self.options.maxInputLength)
        self.$container.addClass('bootstrap-tagsinput-max');

      self.$element.trigger($.Event('itemAdded', {
        item: item,
        options: options
      }));
    },

    /**
     * Removes the given item. Pass true to dontPushVal to prevent updating the
     * elements val()
     */
    remove: function(item, dontPushVal, options) {
      var self = this;

      if (self.objectItems) {
        if (typeof item === "object")
          item = $.grep(self.itemsArray, function(other) {
            return self.options.itemValue(other) == self.options.itemValue(item);
          });
        else
          item = $.grep(self.itemsArray, function(other) {
            return self.options.itemValue(other) == item;
          });

        item = item[item.length - 1];
      }

      if (item) {
        var beforeItemRemoveEvent = $.Event('beforeItemRemove', {
          item: item,
          cancel: false,
          options: options
        });
        self.$element.trigger(beforeItemRemoveEvent);
        if (beforeItemRemoveEvent.cancel)
          return;

        $('.tag', self.$container).filter(function() {
          return $(this).data('item') === item;
        }).remove();
        $('option', self.$element).filter(function() {
          return $(this).data('item') === item;
        }).remove();
        if ($.inArray(item, self.itemsArray) !== -1)
          self.itemsArray.splice($.inArray(item, self.itemsArray), 1);
      }

      if (!dontPushVal)
        self.pushVal();

      // Remove class when reached maxTags
      if (self.options.maxTags > self.itemsArray.length)
        self.$container.removeClass('bootstrap-tagsinput-max');

      self.$element.trigger($.Event('itemRemoved', {
        item: item,
        options: options
      }));
    },

    /**
     * Removes all items
     */
    removeAll: function() {
      var self = this;

      $('.tag', self.$container).remove();
      $('option', self.$element).remove();

      while (self.itemsArray.length > 0)
        self.itemsArray.pop();

      self.pushVal();
    },

    /**
     * Refreshes the tags so they match the text/value of their corresponding
     * item.
     */
    refresh: function() {
      var self = this;
      $('.tag', self.$container).each(function() {
        var $tag = $(this),
          item = $tag.data('item'),
          itemValue = self.options.itemValue(item),
          itemText = self.options.itemText(item),
          tagClass = self.options.tagClass(item);

        // Update tag's class and inner text
        $tag.attr('class', null);
        $tag.addClass('tag ' + htmlEncode(tagClass));
        $tag.contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == 3;
        })[0].nodeValue = htmlEncode(itemText);

        if (self.isSelect) {
          var option = $('option', self.$element).filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('item') === item;
          });
          option.attr('value', itemValue);
        }
      });
    },

    /**
     * Returns the items added as tags
     */
    items: function() {
      return this.itemsArray;
    },

    /**
     * Assembly value by retrieving the value of each item, and set it on the
     * element.
     */
    pushVal: function() {
      var self = this,
        val = $.map(self.items(), function(item) {
          return self.options.itemValue(item).toString();
        });

      self.$element.val(val, true).trigger('change');
    },

    /**
     * Initializes the tags input behaviour on the element
     */
    build: function(options) {
      var self = this;

      self.options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
      // When itemValue is set, freeInput should always be false
      if (self.objectItems)
        self.options.freeInput = false;

      makeOptionItemFunction(self.options, 'itemValue');
      makeOptionItemFunction(self.options, 'itemText');
      makeOptionFunction(self.options, 'tagClass');

      // Typeahead Bootstrap version 2.3.2
      if (self.options.typeahead) {
        var typeahead = self.options.typeahead || {};

        makeOptionFunction(typeahead, 'source');

        self.$input.typeahead($.extend({}, typeahead, {
          source: function(query, process) {
            function processItems(items) {
              var texts = [];

              for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                var text = self.options.itemText(items[i]);
                map[text] = items[i];
                texts.push(text);
              }
              process(texts);
            }

            this.map = {};
            var map = this.map,
              data = typeahead.source(query);

            if ($.isFunction(data.success)) {
              // support for Angular callbacks
              data.success(processItems);
            } else if ($.isFunction(data.then)) {
              // support for Angular promises
              data.then(processItems);
            } else {
              // support for functions and jquery promises
              $.when(data)
                .then(processItems);
            }
          },
          updater: function(text) {
            self.add(this.map[text]);
            return this.map[text];
          },
          matcher: function(text) {
            return (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
          },
          sorter: function(texts) {
            return texts.sort();
          },
          highlighter: function(text) {
            var regex = new RegExp('(' + this.query + ')', 'gi');
            return text.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
          }
        }));
      }

      // typeahead.js
      if (self.options.typeaheadjs) {
        var typeaheadConfig = null;
        var typeaheadDatasets = {};

        // Determine if main configurations were passed or simply a dataset
        var typeaheadjs = self.options.typeaheadjs;
        if ($.isArray(typeaheadjs)) {
          typeaheadConfig = typeaheadjs[0];
          typeaheadDatasets = typeaheadjs[1];
        } else {
          typeaheadDatasets = typeaheadjs;
        }

        self.$input.typeahead(typeaheadConfig, typeaheadDatasets).on('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function(obj, datum) {
          if (typeaheadDatasets.valueKey)
            self.add(datum[typeaheadDatasets.valueKey]);
          else
            self.add(datum);
          self.$input.typeahead('val', '');
        }, self));
      }

      self.$container.on('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
        if (!self.$element.attr('disabled')) {
          self.$input.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        self.$input.focus();
      }, self));

      if (self.options.addOnBlur && self.options.freeInput) {
        self.$input.on('focusout', $.proxy(function(event) {
          // HACK: only process on focusout when no typeahead opened, to
          //       avoid adding the typeahead text as tag
          if ($('.typeahead, .twitter-typeahead', self.$container).length === 0) {
            self.add(self.$input.val());
            self.$input.val('');
          }
        }, self));
      }


      self.$container.on('keydown', 'input', $.proxy(function(event) {
        var $input = $(event.target),
          $inputWrapper = self.findInputWrapper();

        if (self.$element.attr('disabled')) {
          self.$input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          return;
        }

        switch (event.which) {
          // BACKSPACE
          case 8:
            if (doGetCaretPosition($input[0]) === 0) {
              var prev = $inputWrapper.prev();
              if (prev.length) {
                self.remove(prev.data('item'));
              }
            }
            break;

            // DELETE
          case 46:
            if (doGetCaretPosition($input[0]) === 0) {
              var next = $inputWrapper.next();
              if (next.length) {
                self.remove(next.data('item'));
              }
            }
            break;

            // LEFT ARROW
          case 37:
            // Try to move the input before the previous tag
            var $prevTag = $inputWrapper.prev();
            if ($input.val().length === 0 && $prevTag[0]) {
              $prevTag.before($inputWrapper);
              $input.focus();
            }
            break;
            // RIGHT ARROW
          case 39:
            // Try to move the input after the next tag
            var $nextTag = $inputWrapper.next();
            if ($input.val().length === 0 && $nextTag[0]) {
              $nextTag.after($inputWrapper);
              $input.focus();
            }
            break;
          default:
            // ignore
        }

        // Reset internal input's size
        var textLength = $input.val().length,
          wordSpace = Math.ceil(textLength / 5),
          size = textLength + wordSpace + 1;
        $input.attr('size', Math.max(this.inputSize, $input.val().length));
      }, self));

      self.$container.on('keypress', 'input', $.proxy(function(event) {
        var $input = $(event.target);

        if (self.$element.attr('disabled')) {
          self.$input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          return;
        }

        var text = $input.val(),
          maxLengthReached = self.options.maxChars && text.length >= self.options.maxChars;
        if (self.options.freeInput && (keyCombinationInList(event, self.options.confirmKeys) || maxLengthReached)) {
          // Only attempt to add a tag if there is data in the field
          if (text.length !== 0) {
            self.add(maxLengthReached ? text.substr(0, self.options.maxChars) : text);
            $input.val('');
          }

          // If the field is empty, let the event triggered fire as usual
          if (self.options.cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        }

        // Reset internal input's size
        var textLength = $input.val().length,
          wordSpace = Math.ceil(textLength / 5),
          size = textLength + wordSpace + 1;
        $input.attr('size', Math.max(this.inputSize, $input.val().length));
      }, self));

      // Remove icon clicked
      self.$container.on('click', '[data-role=remove]', $.proxy(function(event) {
        if (self.$element.attr('disabled')) {
          return;
        }
        self.remove($(event.target).closest('.tag').data('item'));
      }, self));

      // Only add existing value as tags when using strings as tags
      if (self.options.itemValue === defaultOptions.itemValue) {
        if (self.$element[0].tagName === 'INPUT') {
          self.add(self.$element.val());
        } else {
          $('option', self.$element).each(function() {
            self.add($(this).attr('value'), true);
          });
        }
      }
    },

    /**
     * Removes all tagsinput behaviour and unregsiter all event handlers
     */
    destroy: function() {
      var self = this;

      // Unbind events
      self.$container.off('keypress', 'input');
      self.$container.off('click', '[role=remove]');

      self.$container.remove();
      self.$element.removeData('tagsinput');
      self.$element.show();
    },

    /**
     * Sets focus on the tagsinput
     */
    focus: function() {
      this.$input.focus();
    },

    /**
     * Returns the internal input element
     */
    input: function() {
      return this.$input;
    },

    /**
     * Returns the element which is wrapped around the internal input. This
     * is normally the $container, but typeahead.js moves the $input element.
     */
    findInputWrapper: function() {
      var elt = this.$input[0],
        container = this.$container[0];
      while (elt && elt.parentNode !== container)
        elt = elt.parentNode;

      return $(elt);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Register JQuery plugin
   */
  $.fn.tagsinput = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    var results = [];

    this.each(function() {
      var tagsinput = $(this).data('tagsinput');
      // Initialize a new tags input
      if (!tagsinput) {
        tagsinput = new TagsInput(this, arg1);
        $(this).data('tagsinput', tagsinput);
        results.push(tagsinput);

        if (this.tagName === 'SELECT') {
          $('option', $(this)).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }

        // Init tags from $(this).val()
        $(this).val($(this).val());
      } else if (!arg1 && !arg2) {
        // tagsinput already exists
        // no function, trying to init
        results.push(tagsinput);
      } else if (tagsinput[arg1] !== undefined) {
        // Invoke function on existing tags input
        if (tagsinput[arg1].length === 3 && arg3 !== undefined) {
          var retVal = tagsinput[arg1](arg2, null, arg3);
        } else {
          var retVal = tagsinput[arg1](arg2);
        }
        if (retVal !== undefined)
          results.push(retVal);
      }
    });

    if (typeof arg1 == 'string') {
      // Return the results from the invoked function calls
      return results.length > 1 ? results : results[0];
    } else {
      return results;
    }
  };

  $.fn.tagsinput.Constructor = TagsInput;

  /**
   * Most options support both a string or number as well as a function as
   * option value. This function makes sure that the option with the given
   * key in the given options is wrapped in a function
   */
  function makeOptionItemFunction(options, key) {
    if (typeof options[key] !== 'function') {
      var propertyName = options[key];
      options[key] = function(item) {
        return item[propertyName];
      };
    }
  }

  function makeOptionFunction(options, key) {
    if (typeof options[key] !== 'function') {
      var value = options[key];
      options[key] = function() {
        return value;
      };
    }
  }
  /**
   * HtmlEncodes the given value
   */
  var htmlEncodeContainer = $('<div />');

  function htmlEncode(value) {
    if (value) {
      return htmlEncodeContainer.text(value).html();
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the position of the caret in the given input field
   * http://flightschool.acylt.com/devnotes/caret-position-woes/
   */
  function doGetCaretPosition(oField) {
    var iCaretPos = 0;
    if (document.selection) {
      oField.focus();
      var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
      oSel.moveStart('character', -oField.value.length);
      iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
    } else if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart == '0') {
      iCaretPos = oField.selectionStart;
    }
    return (iCaretPos);
  }

  /**
   * Returns boolean indicates whether user has pressed an expected key combination.
   * @param object keyPressEvent: JavaScript event object, refer
   *     http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html
   * @param object lookupList: expected key combinations, as in:
   *     [13, {which: 188, shiftKey: true}]
   */
  function keyCombinationInList(keyPressEvent, lookupList) {
    var found = false;
    $.each(lookupList, function(index, keyCombination) {
      if (typeof(keyCombination) === 'number' && keyPressEvent.which === keyCombination) {
        found = true;
        return false;
      }

      if (keyPressEvent.which === keyCombination.which) {
        var alt = !keyCombination.hasOwnProperty('altKey') || keyPressEvent.altKey === keyCombination.altKey,
          shift = !keyCombination.hasOwnProperty('shiftKey') || keyPressEvent.shiftKey === keyCombination.shiftKey,
          ctrl = !keyCombination.hasOwnProperty('ctrlKey') || keyPressEvent.ctrlKey === keyCombination.ctrlKey;
        if (alt && shift && ctrl) {
          found = true;
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    return found;
  }

  /**
   * Initialize tagsinput behaviour on inputs and selects which have
   * data-role=tagsinput
   */
  $(function() {
    $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
  });
})(window.jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'Another Model');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'TestCam7');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'TestCam4');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'Profanity');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'An Anddress');
  $('select').tagsinput('add', 'This is a very very very very very very long filter');
});
```

Trick's 2: Using this 2 media query only you can achieve the same output. [Trick's 2 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/dvyh6zcv/1/)

```
 @media (min-width: 1076px) and (min-width: 979px) {
  .row-fluid .span2 {
    margin-left: 15.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-fluid .span2 {
    margin-left: 25.5%;
  }
}
```